# How to read serial number from text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file which contain of lots of information, but i only want to show the serial number of the text file. I am able to read and show the whole line of the serial number in label, but i only required the serial number in the format of ["BcXXXXX"]. Anyone would able to guide through?

```
        string path = @"D:\Sample.txt";
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                String str = sr.ReadLine();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "Bc"))
                    buffer.Append(str);
                string s = buffer.Append(str);
                int start = s.IndexOf("["Bc") + 1;
                int end = s.IndexOf(""]" , start);
                string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
                label2.Text = result.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: What does the actual file look like? Can you post a sample in your question?

Comment: What are the unique characteristics of serial number? For example if in a given line only serial number is enclosed inside square brackets you can get it easily by finding opening and closing of square brackets?!

Comment: Maybe this `\[(Bc\d*)\]`, taking `Group[1].Value` if you need just the serial number (leaving out the brackets). If `XXXXX` are digits.

Comment: Or `\[(Bc.*?)\]` if they're not. Anyway, you should post a sample/description of what you're looking for.

Comment: 2019-02-27 10:25:59,734 [1] DEBUG - SystemUpdateService.OnStartupComplete: Exited
2019-02-27 10:32:28,195 [145] DEBUG - SystemUpdateApplicationInterface.PublishModuleConfigurationChangedEvent: {"NewModuleConfiguration":{"205":["Bc02688"]}}
2019-02-27 10:33:23,294 [153] DEBUG - SystemUpdateApplicationInterface.PublishModuleConfigurationChangedEvent: {"NewModuleConfiguration":{"214":["TBD03240"]}}

Comment: Above is part of the txt file, it show that the serial number is Bc02688, but in the text file it is written ["Bc02688"] as i required to create a start and end for the string to read the serial number only

Answer (score 0):

```
string serialNumber = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\Sample.txt")
.Select(line =>
{
    var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, @"^\[""(.*)""\]$");
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
}).FirstOrDefault(sn => sn != null);
```